# How to delete optional instance variable in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I would like to make the optional parameter workout of my class friend removable/deletable. Has anybody an idea what the best practice is to do that? I've heard you should avoid explicitly setting a variable to null!?

At the moment I am doing the following.

```
class Friend {
  final String firstname;
  final String lastname;
  final String username;
  final String userId;
  Workout workout;

  Friend(
      {this.firstname,
      this.lastname,
      @required this.username,
      @required this.userId,
      this.workout});

  String get displayName => firstname + ' ' + lastname;

  void removeWorkout() {
    workout = null;
  }
```

Appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not explicitly set a variable to null when it is instantiated. However, with what you have right now, when you create an instance of Friend, workout will stay null unless you give it a value.

Having the removeWorkout() method is fine, as this is not instantiating it to null, just removing the value later on. I dont see any problem with leaving it how it is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what Workout class is but normally you can just use the function to check whether the variable is null or not.

As I assume that Workout is some kind of Widget variable :

```
class Friend {
  final String firstname;
  final String lastname;
  final String username;
  final String userId;
  Workout workout;

  Friend({
      this.firstname,
      this.lastname,
      @required this.username,
      @required this.userId,
      this.workout,
  });

  String get displayName => firstname + ' ' + lastname;

  Widget isWorkout() { //Check null value here, if it null just return something else so it is not null anymore
    return workout == null ? Container() : workout;
  }
```